# Generating auto increment unique ID which contain today date, month, year and some number in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I want to create a auto generate unique Id which contains today's date, month, year and some number.

Ex. in year 2016-only 16 will be used, for the month of January 01 will be used, and for today's day 26 would be used, and the slno is starts 0001 to 9999

So my id should be like `1601250001`.

The date changes everyday.

I have tried but not working please rectify my code

```
Create procedure InsertRegistration
(
    @name nvarchar(50),
    @Address nvarchar(100)
)
as
begin
    DECLARE @BdID VARCHAR(25)

    SET @BdID = (SELECT convert(varchar, getdate(), 112))+
                 CAST(((SELECT COUNT(*) 
                     FROM BasicInformation  
                 WHERE @BdID like (SELECT convert(varchar, getdate(),112))+'%') 
                       +1 ) AS VARCHAR(5))

     Insert into BasicInformation(BdID, name, address) 
     values (@BdID, @name, @address)
end
```

It's working but the increment is not happening for each registration. I am a beginner. Please help me

Comment: "But its not working " - is not a question....

Comment: @Mitch ..means its working but the last number cann't change every registration

Comment: Any one who know ????Pls ..

Comment: I found that no one should able to give this answer ...I am the beginer no one help me.....

Comment: @Abhi Welcome to stackoverflow. 
Your question was only posted 2 hours ago, please be patient. Also, it's not a very high quality question, that fact deters a lot of people from answering it. For future questions, please read [ask].

Comment: @Zohar....Ok....i am waiting ur response...

Answer (score 0):

Sql server already have an auto increment mechanism that works better than any user defined code. You should use that instead of creating your own. Simply create an int column and specify it as identity.
Note: use this column as your primary key!

For the column you want you can use a [computed column](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188300.aspx) based on the value of the date entered and the value of the identity column.

Here is a sample code, tested and working on sql server 2014:

Create the udf to compute the column (must be created **before** the table is created):

```
CREATE FUNCTION udf_ComputeColumn
(
    @id int,
    @CreateDate date
)
RETURNS char(8) 
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @revtal char(8),
        @NumberOfRowsToday int

-- get the number of rows inserted in the same day before the current row
SELECT @NumberOfRowsToday = COUNT(*) 
FROM dbo.tblTest 
WHERE Test_CreateDate = @CreateDate
AND Test_Id < @Id

-- calculate the string to return
SELECT @revtal = CONVERT(char(4), @CreateDate, 12) + 
                 RIGHT('0000' + CAST(@NumberOfRowsToday as varchar), 4)
RETURN @revtal 

END
GO
```

Create the test table:

```
CREATE TABLE tblTest
(
    Test_id int identity(1,1) primary key,
    Test_CreateDate date default(GETDATE()),
    Test_dataColumn int,
    Test_Computed as dbo.udf_ComputeColumn(Test_id, Test_CreateDate) -- here is where the magic happens :-)
)
GO
```

Test - insert some values and select them to see if we get the desired result:

```
INSERT INTO tblTest(Test_dataColumn) 
VALUES (0), (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7), (8), (9)

INSERT INTO tblTest(Test_dataColumn) 
VALUES (10), (11), (12), (13), (14), (15), (16), (17), (18), (19)

SELECT * FROM tblTest
```

Results:

```
Test_id     Test_Computed Test_CreateDate Test_dataColumn
----------- ------------- --------------- ---------------
1           16010000      2016-01-26      0
2           16010001      2016-01-26      1
3           16010002      2016-01-26      2
4           16010003      2016-01-26      3
5           16010004      2016-01-26      4
6           16010005      2016-01-26      5
7           16010006      2016-01-26      6
8           16010007      2016-01-26      7
9           16010008      2016-01-26      8
10          16010009      2016-01-26      9
11          16010010      2016-01-26      10
12          16010011      2016-01-26      11
13          16010012      2016-01-26      12
14          16010013      2016-01-26      13
15          16010014      2016-01-26      14
16          16010015      2016-01-26      15
17          16010016      2016-01-26      16
18          16010017      2016-01-26      17
19          16010018      2016-01-26      18
20          16010019      2016-01-26      19
```

Clean up:

```
DROP TABLE tblTest
DROP FUNCTION udf_ComputeColumn
```

Comment: @Zohar...Where to write Insert query.. in stored Procedure

Comment: I didn't write any stored procedures in my example. The Insert I've written is just for testing that the computed column actually contains the desired data...